# Implementing 2D multiple bodies collision resolution

Tags: algorithm, geometry, game-physics, 2d-games

I am trying to make a 2D collision detection and resolution engine without physics elements like impulses, forces etc. This is a good illustration of what i need, with two polygon collision:

[2D Polygon Collision Detection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15573/D-Polygon-Collision-Detection)

I've learned how Separating Axis Theorem works and how to use it to detect two polygons intersection and resolve it. However, I have a problem in implementing multiple bodies collision resolution. Here is an example of such case:

[image]

Rectangular body A moves up with velocity V and intersects with two static triangles.

Which algorithm can I use to resolve such collisions and find amount and direction of displacement that I need to apply to the body to prevent the penetration?

Comment: A first observation: this is not in general harder than 2-body collision resolution, because if the 2 triangles were a single polygon (e.g. if they were connected by a thin horizontal strip near the top) then the solution to the problem would be unchanged.  Or does the resolution algorithm only work for pairs of convex polygons?

Comment: The algorithm only works with convex polygons.

Answer (score 0):

We can simplify the problem if we add the following restriction: the body can move only along its velocity vector.
Then, there are at least two options.

1. If you have an algorithm which tells whether two bodies collide, you can run a binary search on the amount of movement (from `0.0*v` to `1.0*v`) after which there is still no collision with any of the bodies.
   Then, move the body (red rectangle in your example) only by that amount.
2. If you have a finer algorithm which can tell you for two bodies the maximal amount of movement along the vector `v` after which there is still no collision, just take the minimum of that value among all the bodies (two triangles in your example).

Comment: This is very helpful if i allow bodies to move only along the velocity vector, but in this case i want them to 'slide' along the polygon edge, like in example program i posted link to.